# Access .accde VBA getting corrupted constantly

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an accdb backend database with an accde front end  which consists of an input form with some VBA validation on a network drive.

However all of a sudden about a week ago I started getting the following error message:

> the database cannot be opened because the vba project contained in it
>   cannot be read

So I went through the following procedure:

1. I replaced the frontend with a backup which immediately got corrupted
2. I replaced both the front and back end with previously functional backups but still the corruption issue again.
3. I rebuilt both files from the ground up but still they keep getting corrupted

I've tested it on my pc and it works fine, transfered it to the network and it may work on a particular pc only to be corrupted by the next one rendering it useless again!

I'm really stumped with this one and I'm in big trouble because it is a critical production DB and all data collection is at a standstill until I can get it up and running again so any help would be really appreciated!! I've been banging my head against a wall with this for 3 days now...

Answer (score 0):

The answer of another person who had a similar problem.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/483554ee-3041-47ab-83a6-f8ad5aca6d66/the-database-cannot-be-opened-because-the-vba-project-contained-in-it-cannot-be-read

Answer marked:

> It was the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\VBA\VBA7\vba7.dll version the one that had the error were
>   7.0.15 and we compiled on 7.0.16 when we overwrote them it no longer gave an error.

Comment: Hi Kim, thank you for the response, I'm sorry I missed it somehow hence the very late reply!! I ended up rolling out the accdb version of the file as I couldn't spend any more time trying to figure it out but I'll have a look at your suggestion when I have time. Thanks again.

Comment: If you managed to solve the problem, that's what matters for you :-)